# Remove repeating text

Tags: jquery

I have a SharePoint page that is littered with text string of **12:00 AM** that I don't want to display; the underlying code is of the form:

```
<td class="ms-cal-workitem">
  <table border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="ms-cal-monthitem">
          <a tabIndex="5" onclick="GoToLink(this);return false;" or 
            <nobr>
              <b>**12:00 AM**
            <br/>
              MORE TEXT
```

Comment: Will the string you don't want to display always be in a `td` with the same class? Or is the only commonality the text-string itself?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just replace the HTML with the time stamp removed?  Something like this:

```
var newMarkup = $('.ms-cal-workitem').html().replace('12:00 AM', '')
$('.ms-cal-workitem').html(newMarkup);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS to hide this element

```
td.ms-cal-monthitem nobr {display: none;}
```